# How to use the same firebase database for two or more apps?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an ios game and its database is created using firebase now i want my database to be linked with the android game too , so how to do it.

Comment: you have answered your question :)

Comment: What's this it is a question answer session? :)

Comment: Where is flag "not a question"? :D

Answer (score 1):

For using the same database of firebase to two or more apps just follow the below steps.

Go to your firebase project console Click on overview at the left top corner Click on add another project. Select your platform Enter the project details asked by firebase download and add the config file to your project. ----You are ready to go.

Note: JSON file Should be same